# How to change the language of an OpenXava application?

Tags: java, internationalization, openxava

I want that my OpenXava application works in multiple languages (English, Japanese and Spanish). How can I set the language of my application to Japanese, for example?

Answer (score 1):

An OpenXava application works by default with the language defined in the user browser as default language. So, if you want see your OpenXava application in Japanese with Chrome, go to the Setting option of Chrome, there open the Advanced options and then open the Languages section. Move Japanese to the firt position of the list. In this way:

[image]

Firefox, Safari and Edge also have options to change the language. Afterwards, reload your OpenXava application in the browser and it will be in Japanese, as following:

[image]

OpenXava has the most common used labels translated to English, Spanish, German, French, Chinese, Russian, Japanese, Portuguese, Catalan, Indonesian, Italian, Polish, Serbian and Swedish, therefore most of the labels will be in Japanese automatically. Although, you can add new translations for your own terms or add a new language easily. Look at the [OpenXava documentation about internationalization](https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/i18n_en.html).

Comment: Nice. But, is there a way to force some language, despite the browser current language?

Comment: Create a servlet filter with Locales.setCurrent(new Locale("pt")), for example